# How do I proceed with this Sudoku puzzle?

Tags: sudoku

[image]

Pairing elimination is done. What's next?

Comment: Which app is this?

Comment: Sudoku - pretty puzzling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [image]

.

> Notice in the top row there are two cells with the only options of $2$ and $9$. This means those two cells will be $2$ and $9$, you just don't know which is which. Therefore you can eliminate every other $2$ and $9$ in that row.

Comment: What is this game, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @user477343 Sudoku. Look at the tag on the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry for not seeing that. Is this the original version of sudoku? I play sudoku, but never have I seen this many numbers on a sudoku grid.

Comment: The small numbers are "notes" -- usually just used to jot down what possibilities go in each square. They're pretty common in a lot of apps.

Answer (score 8):

> [image]

.

> The circled square has the only 5 in the top left box.

Comment: Oh yes, thats one way.